# JavaScript: algorithm of detect and remove similar strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, similarity

Imagine that I have a JS array shown below:

```
0 - The Big Bang Theory - Fourth Season
1 - The Big Bang Theory - Third Season
2 - The Big Bang Theory - Second Season
3 - The Big Bang Theory - First Season
4 - The Big Bang Theory - First Season (2007)
5 - The Big Bang Theory - Fourth Season (2010)
6 - The Big Bang Theory - Second Season (2008)
7 - The Big Bang Theory - Third Season (2009)
8 - The Big Bang Theory: Access All Areas (2012)
9 - The Big Bang Theory: It All Started with a Big Bang (2012)
```

and we know some of the items are similar. The output should be like the below array:

```
0 - The Big Bang Theory - Fourth Season
1 - The Big Bang Theory - Third Season
2 - The Big Bang Theory - Second Season
3 - The Big Bang Theory - First Season
8 - The Big Bang Theory: Access All Areas (2012)
9 - The Big Bang Theory: It All Started with a Big Bang (2012)
```

What can I do to omit the similar items? What solution do you have?

Thanks

Comment: You could write some code. It could detect and group the similar ones. It could be in JavaScript.

Comment: google fuzzy text matching

Comment: @Marty I know i should write some code :) but i shared my question in stackoverflow to achieve a quicker solution.

Comment: @skav Thanks to help

Comment: *"to achieve a quicker solution"* ... assumes this is a code writing service, which it is not. You are expected to show your code efforts and research and ask questions here as a last resort, not as a quick way to have someone else do your work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove the bit in parentheses from each title, dump it into a Set -- which eliminates duplicates, and turn it back to an array:

```
movies = [...new Set(movies.map(movie => movie.replace(/\s*\(\d+\)\s*$/g, '')))];
```

```js
movies = [
'The Big Bang Theory - Fourth Season',
'The Big Bang Theory - Third Season',
'The Big Bang Theory - Second Season',
'The Big Bang Theory - First Season',
'The Big Bang Theory - First Season (2007)',
'The Big Bang Theory - Fourth Season (2010)',
'The Big Bang Theory - Second Season (2008)',
'The Big Bang Theory - Third Season (2009)',
'The Big Bang Theory: Access All Areas (2012)',
'The Big Bang Theory: It All Started with a Big Bang (2012)'];

movies = [...new Set(movies.map(movie => movie.replace(/\s*\(\d+\)\s*$/g, '')))];

console.log(movies);
```